# Git on Azure using common tools such as SourceTree

Tags: git, azure, version-control, azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I cannot see a way to configure sourcetree to use GIT on Azure (DevOps).  I tried using the token you can generate in the DevOps tool, but that doesn't seem to plug in anywhere.

Is it possible to use Sourcetree with GIT running on Azure DevOps, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Git on Azure Devops together with other tools. The easiest thing is to install the Git Credential Manager (comes with Git for Windows), it will handle the OAuth workflow.

All of the interaction with Azure DevOps needs to happen from the <kbd>local</kbd> -> <kbd>Clone</kbd> screen:
[image]

I don't know what reasoning the Sourcetree has for not implementing the "Remote" features to list Azure Devops accounts and repositories. The REST APIs are readily available. I suggest you send them a feature request.

But it can work without that. You need to create alternate credentials (git credentials) and set a username+password for your account. You can use those credentials as your username+password for the git repository.

Alternatively, you can create a Personal Access Token with the correct permissions. Then enter any username or simply `.` or your account name (`devops.azure.com/MyAccount` => `MyAccount`) and the Personal Access Token for your password.

Your final option is to use the SSH option in Aure Devops (you need to set it up for your account).

Comment: What you talk about is for other things than pure git (i.e. PR, issues,...). Just clone the repository and enter the credentials when they will be requested.